# Active Directory default + specific attributes in one LDAP call?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm retrieving info from an Active Directory setup via LDAP (using Python, although that's probably not important).  I can retrieve a specific user account via a search command, and I get a few dozen attributes, presumably the ones that Active Directory is set to return by default.  These do not include `"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"` attribute, which is an AD computed attribute that doesn't come back by default.

I can request it by using the attrlist parameter in the Python search call (`attrlist=["msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed", "sAMAccountName"]`), but I then have to know and enumerate all the attributes I'm interested in.  I was wondering if there is any LDAP syntax for `'attrlist'` that would indicate that I want all the default attributes that would have come back anyway, plus any others I might explicitly indicate?  Perhaps some sort of wildcard like `attrlist=['*', 'msDS-UserPasswordExpireTimeComputed']`, for instance.  Or do I have to make one call to get all the default attributes, and a second to retrieve others?

Also, how does an AD installation determine what attributes are returned by default?  Is it standard to AD, or customizable by admins?